# What is the easiest way to run IIS on a virtual machine on Azure?

Tags: iis, azure

I already managed to create web service on azure and create a virtual machine, i didnt see any option to merge them so i can use the web service capabilities ( such as easy deploy ) but still use the virtual machine disk and running a window service.

is there a simple article on what is the best approch for this configuration ?

Thannks

Comment: Do you definitely need a VM role? It's easier with a web role, unless you have some particular need for a VM role...

Comment: When you say "web service on azure" and "easy deploy" are you saying you created a web service running on a Windows Azure Web Site, or is it a Web Role running in Cloud Services?

Comment: You're question is kind of not clear, can you clarify what do you mean by merge? and what is your intention ? if you need to run a website you have several choices one is web role the other is vm as IaaS or simply website, I recommend you go for websites which is very easy to deploy and maintain using MVC4 or ASP .NET

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:

File New project -> Cloud -> WCF Service Web Role or ASPNET MVC 4 Web Role and create a Web Api.